# getc(stdin) does not record '+' and '-' in one variation, however it takes in '*' and '/'

Tags: c

```
int main(void) {

    char z;
    while ( (z = getc(stdin)) != EOF) {
        printf("%c", z);
    }

    int  d, flag = 0;
    char c;

    while ((flag = fscanf(stdin, "%d", &d)) != EOF) {
        if (flag == 1) {
            printf("%d", d);
        } else {
            c = getc(stdin);
            printf("%c", c);
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Hi, i have two variations here, there first one is char z which gets the character from input stream and prints it out. it returns exactly what i typed.

The second variation prints out exactly what i type except for the operators '+' and '-'. Kindly enlighten me here. I am confused as multiplication and division works in this variation and not + and -. Below is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the input and output of the above code]

Comment: FYI: getc() returns an "int", not a "char".

Answer (score 0):

Because `+2` is a valid integer, so it is reading all of that in the `fscanf(%d)`, same with `-2`, which should be a little more obvious.

So `fscanf(%d)` reads `1`, then on the next iteration, happily reads `+2` or `-2` as an integer.

The `+` sign is lost in the output since `printf()` does not print the sign for positive integers by default.

Answer (score 0):

The `%d` format specifier to `scanf` looks for an integer.  Since a `+` or `-` preceding some digits is a valid representation of a number, they are read as part of that number.

So when you input `1+2`, the `1` gets picked up on the first loop iteration, then `+2` gets picked up on the second iteration.  When you then print with `%d`, the leading `+` is not printed by default.

If you were to input `1-2`, you would get the same as output.  However instead of reading `1`, then `-`, then `2`, it reads `1` then `-2`.  The `-` still gets printed because it is relevant.

Comment: Thanks everyone for imparting the concepts and pointing out my mistakes. Appreciate it.